# Android Button Works Only on the second Click

Tags: java, android, button

I am Developing my first android Calculator app. I'm stuck with a single defect. I have added few buttons and on clicking those buttons, it will put the respectives text on the `EditText` Field. The Main Problem is described below,
              When on running the project, the buttons have to be clicked twice to put the respective text on the `EditText` field for the first time. For example, `Button1` puts '1' on the `EditText` field on click. When on run, First click on that button does nothing. Only on the second click it puts '1' on the `EditText` field.

The Code follows,

XML Button and EditField,

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:hint="@string/textView1" />
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"        
        android:layout_width="60dp"       
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:hint="@string/button1"
        android:onClick="set1" />
```

---

**MainActivity.java**

The respective function for Button onClick,

```
public void set1(View v){
    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                EditText tv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                String text=tv.getText().toString();
                tv.setText(text+"1");
            }
    });

}
```

Comment: you dont require findviewby id in set1() because you allready declared it in XML file.so setonclicklistner() is called directly from xml file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your `set1()` method as follows,

```
public void set1(View v)
{
    EditText tv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String text=tv.getText().toString();
    tv.setText(text+"1");
}
```

Comment: Dear, @Kedarnath, Thank You! For sooooo long time I was fighting my way through all this _findViewById_"s and _setOnClickListener_"s to make such easy & simple thing as click. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling your `set1()` method onClick of button in xml then you don't need to find ID for button in that method again. So simply it looks like,

```
public void set1(View v)
{
  EditText tv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  String text=tv.getText().toString();
  tv.setText(text+"1");
}
```

Now in your xml for button will be

```
android:onClick="set1"
```